# Problem installing Python module gdal on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python

I am having problems installing Python module `gdal` on Ubuntu Jammy (22.04). I have `libgdal-dev` and `gdal-bin` installed on the system. I installed the `gdal module` specifying the same version of `gdal`, i.e. `pip install gdal==3.4.1`. I did not manage to install it with `pip` without specifying the version.

When I run in Python `from osgeo import gdal`, I obtain the following error message:

```
ImportError: /home/fabiola/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /lib/libgdal.so.30)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-61e0eefce4de> in <module>
----> 1 from osgeo import gdal

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in <module>
     43 
     44 
---> 45 _gdal = swig_import_helper()
     46 del swig_import_helper
     47 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in swig_import_helper()
     40                 traceback_string = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
     41                 raise ImportError(traceback_string + '\n' + msg)
---> 42         return importlib.import_module('_gdal')
     43 
     44 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'
```

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, and this already caused me some problems with some software that I needed to reinstall. I do not know if this element may be of relevance also in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal` and `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal` set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones in a hurry:

```bash
# ubuntu 22.04
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev gdal-config
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$(gdal-config --cflags | sed 's/-I//')
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$(gdal-config --cflags | sed 's/-I//')
pip install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version)
```